# Link styling only specific links in a list

Tags: css

I have a list CSS style that looks like this:

```
.my-list {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    a { color: #000000; }
}
```

I would like to style the color of certain links inside this list with another color. How can I do this?

```
<li class=my-list>

    <a href="www.blah.com">this link is black</a>

    <a href="www.blahblah.com">I WANT THIS LINK TO BE ANOTHER COLOR</a>

</li>
```

I would like a CSS solution to this problem that does not require manually changing the link color. I have many of these lists, and a manual solution is not feasible.

Comment: Assigning these "special" links a distinct class and then styling it would be the proper solution.

Comment: The `nth-child` pseudo class is good for styling based on an element's position within a parent element (think zebra striping tables), but a poor choice if you're styling something that has a special purpose.  If your element needs specific styling for reasons other than its position, then a class/id should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `nth-child` CSS3 selector to select `<a>` element by it's index within `<li>`:

```
.my-list a:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6hCWY/

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `a` after `mylist` to indicate you want to apply this `CSS` to `a` tags. You could use `pseudo selectors, first-child, nth-child` to select specific tags within the list:

```
.my-list a {
    background-color : #000000; 
}
```

Using the `first-child` pseudo selector.

```
.my-list a:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**To select the 2nd link in your list**

Use the `nth-child selector`:

```
.my-list a:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JSSJ/

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.my-list {
  //some styles here
}
.my-list a {
  //some styles for links here
}
```

You cannot nest CSS within blocks, it is not like a programming language. The only case where you nest a block within another is for defining media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the links that you want a different color:

```
.my-list {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.my-list a.diffcolor {
    color:red

}
```

Then you can just mark the ones you want to have that color with the class.

```
<li class=my-list>

    <a href="www.blah.com">this link is black</a>

    <a href="www.blahblah.com" class="diffcolor">I WANT THIS LINK TO BE ANOTHER COLOR</a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an addtional CSS class or use the attribute selector http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/